# Extracting individual trees from DSM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem

I am trying to extract individual trees from a high resolution DSM in QGIS. I need to identify the trees and extract their individual height from the raster. Assuming I have identified the areas that I know contain trees, what tool can I use to get this information? Perhaps using some kind of local maxima?

Comment: If you're interested, this is not directly an answer but it's a really nice study on forest data extraction from [ALS](http://gmv.cast.uark.edu/scanning-2/airborne-laser-scanning/) and imagery; https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/262809?

Answer (score 3):

You can for example try Saga's "Local minima and maxima" tool:

[image]